# How do you format a Word document content control bound to a Custom Xml Part

Tags: report, saas, dynamics-business-central, word-contentcontrol

We have a Word document that contains a table bound to a Custom Xml Part. One of the fields is a date which is bound to a Text Content Control. The formatting is MMM dd, yyyy. How do you change the date format to something else (e.g. MM/dd/yyyy)?

The report column in question is defined as follows:

```
column(DateName, Format("Date Name", 0, 4)
{
}
```

What is frustrating is that format returns the full month name which means there could be a lot of needless wrapping for the long month names.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
1. Created a Report extension and added 2 additional columns
   a. Formatted column used with Text Content Control
      works as expected
   b. Date column used with Date Picker Content Control
      Report does NOT honor formatting properties set in Content Control
      Always displays with the time component

add(DatasetName)
{
    column(DateName_Formatted; Format("Date Name", 0, '<Month,2>/<Day,2>/<Year4>') 
    { 
    }
    column(DateName_Date; "Date name") 
    { 
    }
}
```

It seems absurd to me, but it appears we have to write a Report Extension just to display a formatted date.

Perhaps this will get better in future versions. After all, it wasn't too long ago that you had to create a brand new report just to add another column to the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Date is formatted to text is that the report might be run in any language. Formatting the Date in the layout could then potentially cause a mismatch between the language of the receiver and his/her expected date format.

Formatting the date before outputting it solves this issue because the date would be formatted according to the language the report is currently using (which can change during report execution).